# Issue with Highchart Update with Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am having an issue with the update highchart with the ajax call. It spoiling the whole Pie chart whenever the ajax call run.

**My Program**

```
$('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Click the slices to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                        }
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Brands',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [<?php echo $cok; ?>]
                }]
            });
```

The `$cok` variable has the values like `{ name: 'No Answer', y: 10, drilldown: 'No Answer' },{ name: 'No Answer', y: 20, drilldown: 'No Answer' }`. But when I update these values in the Piechart using the ajax call it destroyed the whole Pie chart.

**My Ajax call :**

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: 'callexport.php',
                 data: {pie_ajax_campaign:'<?php echo $_SESSION['scampaign']; ?>',pie_ajax_date:$("#daterange").val() },
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(piedata)
                 {
                    $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Click the slices to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                        }
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Brands',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [piedata]
                }]
            });
                    return false;
                }});


            },20000);
```

Comment: Can you show how the piedata looks like?

Comment: its same like the above php variable, those i am passing into the data.

Comment: So the chart appears after the ajax call, but you dont want to destroy the whold chart? If you want to update only data in the chart, then use series.setData() method. https://jsfiddle.net/ctqb3515/